# Call API Gateway Method with IAM Authorization from Swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm working on a Swift project that calls multiple methods built in AWS API Gateway. These methods require IAM Authorization, i have tested this methods with the Postman REST Client using AWS Signature V4 with my credentials, but i don't know if it is the lack of documentation or something else but i can't figure out how to apply the AWS Signature from my Swift project.

The most related topic i found (it is commented in Client Class that AWS ships in the SDK as well) is to add this code to the delegate or before the call, because the client is a Singleton:

```
 let credentialProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .USEast1, identityPoolId: "YourIdentityPoolId")
 let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USEast1, credentialsProvider: credentialProvider)
 AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
```

I'm pretty sure this code uses Cognito for signing in, but i don't want to add Cognito to my project, i have my own Database an user pool outside AWS.

Note: The Swift calls work well when i disable IAM Authorization in the API methods.

The call:

```
let client = PRUEBAPruebaClient.defaultClient()
client.petstorewalkthroughFlattenallGet().continueWithBlock({(task: AWSTask) -> AnyObject? in
        self.showResult(task)
        return nil
    })
func showResult(task: AWSTask) {
    if let error = task.error {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    } else if let result = task.result {
        print(result)
    }
}
```

The response:

```
Error: Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSAPIGatewayErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)" UserInfo={HTTPBody={
    message = "Missing Authentication Token";
}, HTTPHeaderFields=<CFBasicHash 0x17407f600 [0x1a81b4bb8]>{type = immutable dict, count = 9,
entries =>
    0 : X-Cache = <CFString 0x170054ee0 [0x1a81b4bb8]>{contents = "Error from cloudfront"}
    1 : Content-Type = <CFString 0x170054c70 [0x1a81b4bb8]>{contents = "application/json"}
    2 : x-amzn-ErrorType = <CFString 0x17007b0c0 [0x1a81b4bb8]>{contents = "MissingAuthenticationTokenException"}
    3 : x-amzn-RequestId = <CFString 0x17007b300 [0x1a81b4bb8]>{contents = "3c410741-d38e-11e6-9d84-09cbdcab48a7"}
    4 : Via = <CFString 0x1700bd040 [0x1a81b4bb8]>{contents = "1.1 9d0536684daddf203ff3b546b85c5dfe.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)"}
    6 : Date = <CFString 0x170054b50 [0x1a81b4bb8]>{contents = "Thu, 05 Jan 2017 21:30:53 GMT"}
    10 : Content-Length = 43
    11 : X-Amz-Cf-Id = <CFString 0x1700996e0 [0x1a81b4bb8]>{contents = "dEYo5M0iFCthvydhiViK2L-DlzwoeX0mSHQ1YTBAtQZL0m_w_jdc2g=="}
    12 : Connection = <CFString 0x170037760 [0x1a81b4bb8]>{contents = "keep-alive"}
}
}
```

Thank you for your help!!!

[Postman call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsF55.png)

[Postman response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AF7g6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to implement authorization on your API Gateway API with your own custom database you have two options:

1. AWS_IAM authorization with [developer authenticated IDs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/developer-authenticated-identities.html). Here is a [Swift code sample](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/blob/developer-authenticated-identities-2-4/CognitoSync-Sample/Swift/CognitoSyncDemo/AmazonClientManager.swift)
2. A [custom authorizer](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-custom-authorizers-in-amazon-api-gateway/):

   > With custom request authorizers, developers can authorize their APIs using bearer token authorization strategies, such as OAuth using an AWS Lambda function. ... You can use Lambda to implement various authorization strategies (e.g., JWT verification, OAuth provider callout).

You won't need to sign your requests with SigV4 if you choose to use a custom authorizer, but you'll still need to pass in some sort of bearer token in the request header. If you choose to go this route it should simplify your client-side Swift code.